# How to vertically centre text in a Xamarin Forms Entry on UWP?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms project (v2.5) where I have a text Entry control in my Xaml file. I need the entry to be taller than default, so I specify a HeightRequest of 60, which works fine, apart from the text itself is aligned to the top of the Entry control.

```
<Entry Text="{Binding CustomerNameText}" HeightRequest="60" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsEnabled="{Binding CustomerNameEntryEnabled}" Focused="Entry_Focused" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I added a custom renderer:

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(this.Control != null)
        {
            this.Control.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            this.Control.Height = 60;
        }

    }

}
```

But this doesn't work. The HeightRequest in the Xaml doesn't seem to work anymore, so I added the height in the custom renderer. But the text alignment stays at the top.

Can anyone tell me how to get the text vertically centered?

Comment: Hi @aritchie have you got solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

The correspondent native control of `Entry` is `TextBox` in UWP app, see [Renderer Base Classes and Native Controls](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/) for more details. The [`VerticalAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_VerticalAlignment) property means that setting current `control` to vertical center in the parent control, not for the text inside. Only properties like [`TextAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_TextAlignment)  will take effects on the text. Since `Textbox` in UWP app doesn't have the property `VerticalTextAlignment`, you cannot set the text to vertical center directly. But you could change the style template of `TextBox` as a workaround.

Create a new style for the `Textbox`, and to set the `VerticalAlignment` property to center to both `ContentPresenter` and `ScrollViewer` controls inside the `ControlTemplate`. And then apply the style in the custom render.

The style in `App.xaml`

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid> 
                  ...
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter  x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center"  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" VerticalAlignment="Center" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" MinWidth="34" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Custom render:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
   base.OnElementChanged(e);

   if (this.Control != null)
   { 
       this.Control.Height = 60; 
       Control.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)App.Current.Resources["TextBoxStyle1"];
   }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to fix my project with the same problem. Would you mind editing your answer to show where these two elements go in the UWP project? In addition, your <Style> is abbreviated, would you mind showing the full markup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is needed a custom renderer, just center and expand.

```
VerticalOptions = "LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but below code works for Android to center text in Entry,it shuold work for UWP too:

```
this.Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;

this.Control.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
```

Let me know,if it helps

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
VerticalOptions = "CenterAndExpand"
```

If this doesn't work go for custom renderer