# Why is my Entry text not centered in my xamarin form

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a xamarin form with an Entry control:

```xml
<Label Text="Subtotal: " TextColor="#000000" HorizontalOptions="End" Font="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
<Entry x:Name="Subtotal" Placeholder="$0.00" BackgroundColor="#f5f5dc" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

I have the `VerticalTextAlignment="Center"` on there, but the text for `Subtotal` is shown on the bottom of the Entry control.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48943410/199364), its a limitation of UWP's native control.  *"Since Textbox in UWP app doesn't have the property VerticalTextAlignment, you cannot set the text to vertical center directly. But you could change the style template of TextBox as a workaround."* See that answer for more details of a work-around.